# "looking back from now": is it looking back from the future to now or looking back to the past from this moment?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

original sentence (1999 China's post-grad entrance exam):

> People looking back 5 or 10 years from now may well wonder why so few companies took the online plunge.

http://www.langlib.com/Reading/SentenceAnalysis/ReadingSentence/NjYxLTQtNA==

And how should I rewrite the sentence that means the other way?

Answer (score 2):

English often changes verb tense and focus depending on the imagined *point of view*.  In this case it is of the future person, looking back at a particular point in time.  The original sentence is saying that, 5 to 10 years from now, people will look back *at this moment* and wonder why something was true.

Another example:

> Although you think your life is hard, **twenty years from now** you will look back and remember how happy you were.

Notice the sentence uses the past tense "how happy you *were*" even though the person is *currently* experiencing that happiness.  This is because the speaker imagines the perspective of the person, twenty years in the future, looking back at a past event.

If instead you want to say a future person looking back on events *even further in the past than the current moment*, the language is not much different.  However you usually have to provide some kind of context to explain the relationship of the different time frames:

> Scholars 10 years from now may look back at **the events that led up to this moment**, and wonder how we ever let things get so bad.

Answer (score 0):

What a great question!

Strictly as it's written, your example sentence is ambiguous and it *could* be interpreted in either way. The verb tenses can be relative to either point in time.

However, it's commonly *used* to refer to people looking back on the present from the future. In that sense, it's taken on a cultural meaning that doesn't allow for misinterpretation without conscious analysis.

To refer to the present looking back on the past, a possible rephrasing is:

> People looking back on the past 5 or 10 years may well wonder why so few companies took the online plunge.

---

To more *explicitly* refer to the future, you could say:

> People 5 or 10 years from now may well look back and wonder why so few companies took the online plunge.

Answer (score 0):

> looking back five or ten years from now...[looking upon the present from a point 5 or 10 years in the future]
>
> looking back from now five or ten years... [looking from the present at what happened 5 or 10 years ago]

Most native speakers would gravitate towards the meaning in brackets as the most likely one, unless there were some contextual reason not to do so.