# "Next year we will have been married for 30 years" and "Next year we will be married for 30 years."

Tags: difference

What's the difference between these senteces?

> Next year we will have been married for 30 years.
>
> Next year we will be married for 30 years.

Comment: See previous questions on this issue:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174871/looking-back-from-now-is-it-looking-back-from-the-future-to-now-or-looking-ba                        
https://books.google.pt/books?id=lx7UAniLfJwC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=English+tense+looking+back+on+event+in+the+future&source=bl&ots=_hN4AN0_AI&sig=ACfU3U0exe85L29Yi6mZhFXZY0OWWquQUw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicybe107PqAhWE2qQKHXy-A9wQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=English%20tense%20looking%20back%20on%20event%20in%20the%20future&f=false

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is correct because it indicates that 30 years have passed since the couple wed, while the second one implies that next year a wedding ceremony will take place which will last for 30 years.